# How can I set up an Ingress to connect to a ClusterIP service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

### Objective

I am have deployed [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) on AWS' [Elastic Kubernetes Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ek) using Airflow's Stable Helm chart. My goal is to create an Ingress to allow others to access the airflow webserver UI via their browser. It's worth mentioning that I am deploying on EKS using AWS Fargate. My experience with Kubernetes is somewhat limited, and I have not set an Ingress myself before.

### What I have tried to do

I am currently able to connect to the airflow web-server pod via port-forwarding (like `kubectl port-forward airflow-web-pod 8080:8080`). I have tried setting the Ingress through the Helm chart (documented [here](https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow)). After which:

Running `kubectl get ingress -n dp-airflow` I got:

```
NAME             CLASS    HOSTS                      ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
airflow-flower   <none>   foo.bar.com             80      3m46s
airflow-web      <none>   foo.bar.com             80      3m46s
```

Then running `kubectl describe ingress airflow-web -n dp-airflow` I get:

```
Name:             airflow-web
Namespace:        dp-airflow
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                      Path  Backends
  ----                      ----  --------
  foo.bar.com
                            /airflow   airflow-web:web (<redacted_ip>:8080)
Annotations:                meta.helm.sh/release-name: airflow
                            meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: dp-airflow
```

I am not sure what did I need to put into the browser, so I have tried using `http://foo.bar.com/airflow` as well as the cluster endpoint/ip without success.

This is how the airflow webservice service looks like:
Running `kubectl get services -n dp-airflow`, I get:

```
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
airflow-web   ClusterIP   <redacted_ip>   <none>        8080/TCP   28m
```

#### Other things I have tried

I have tried creating an Ingress without the Helm chart (I am using Terraform), like:

```sh
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "airflow_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name = "ingress"
  }

  spec {
    backend {
      service_name = "airflow-web"
      service_port = 8080
    }

    rule {
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "airflow-web"
            service_port = 8080
          }
          path = "/airflow"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However I was still not able to connect to the web UI. What are the steps that I need to take to set up an Ingress? Which address do I need to use in my browser to connect to the web UI?

I am happy to provide further details if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sound like you have created [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) resources. That is a good step. But for those Ingress resources to have any effect, you also need an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) than can *realize* your Ingress to an actual *load balancer*.

In an AWS environment, you should look at [AWS Load Balancer Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller) that creates an [AWS Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html) that is configured according your Ingress resources.

> Ingress to connect to a ClusterIP service?

First, the default load balancer is *classic load balancer*, but you probably want to use the newer *Application Load Balancer* to be used for your Ingress resources, so on your Ingress resources add this annotation:

```
annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
```

By default, your services should be of type `NodePort`, but as you request, it is possible to use `ClusterIP` services as well, when you on your Ingress resource also add this annotation (for traffic mode):

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
```

See the [ALB Ingress documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html) for more on this.

Comment: Hi @Jonas. How do I connect to reach port 8080 after setting up the controller? In other words, what do I need to curl?

Comment: You should curl the host that is in the status-part of your `Ingress`-resource + the path you want to reach. If you really want to let your load balancer to listen to another port than 8080, have a look at configuring listener on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html#environments-cfg-alb-console-listeners

Comment: Looks promising! Will set it up and come back later with separate (hopefully better) questions

Comment: I added more details to my answer regarding ClusterIP

Comment: You may also need this annotation:

`alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing`

Thanks for the good answer @Jonas

Comment: Note this caveat from the linked ALB Ingress documentation: **"The IP target type is required when target Pods are running on Fargate."**